# redundant legends in python matplot lib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am plotting two conditions and want only two legends. But there are replicates in my data, and I am getting a separate legend for each replicate. Why? I apologize if this has previously been addressed, but I have spent an embarrassing amount of time on this and much of what I find seems overly complex for my situation. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#####read and organize data
alldata = pd.read_csv('Fig_1.csv')

CondtionA = list(zip(alldata.iloc[:,1],alldata.iloc[:,2]))
ConditionB = list(zip(alldata.iloc[:,7],alldata.iloc[:,8]))

### make the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

plt.plot(alldata['Temperature'],ConditionA,linewidth = 1,c='k', linestyle = '--',label = 'ConditionA')
plt.plot(alldata['Temperature'],ConditionB,linewidth = 1,c='k', label = "ConditonB")
ax.legend(numpoints=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It would help to know what Fig_1.csv looks like (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Noah You're right, that should be part of the question. But since apparently the OP wasn't aware of that, I created a [mcve] within my answer below, which you may use to reproduce this case.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you have gone above and beyond in your answer and I have voted you up for your kindness and useful answer :)

Answer (score 2):

#### a) use returned lines

You should be able to create a legend from only the first item of the returned lines of each `plot` call.

```
lines1 = plt.plot(...)
lines2 = plt.plot(...)

plt.legend(handles=(lines1[0], lines2[0]), labels=("Label A", "Label B"))
```

The drawback here is that you need to name the labels again manually.

#### b) select every second legend handle/label

If that is undesired, but if in turn you know that you want to use every second handle and label from the originally created legend, you can get those handles and labels via `get_legend_handles_labels()`.

```
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(handles[::2], labels[::2])
```

---

Reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(10)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.arange(10)

a = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(10,2), axis=0), axis=1)
b = np.cumsum(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(10,2), axis=0), axis=1)+6


lines1 = plt.plot(x,a, label="Label A", color="k")
lines2 = plt.plot(x,b, label="Label B", color="k", linestyle="--")

# either:
plt.legend(handles=(lines1[0], lines2[0]), labels=("Label A", "Label B"))

# or alternatively:
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
plt.legend(handles[::2], labels[::2])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I will need to play with this more tomorrow. I gave this a shot and got an interesting outcome where legend title said "---Line2D(ConditionA)" and "---Line2D(ConditionB)". Not sure where the "Line2D" part came from...So not quite there yet, but the approach sounds reasonable. Thanks again for your help, I'll post back when I have time to look into this further.

Comment: I see. I took the time to produce a [mcve] and provide two tested solutions. Note that creating such examples is annoying, it should be the duty of the questioner, not the answerer.

Comment: I apologize for not including the data and see now how I inadvertently made it harder for people to answer the question I asked. I'll make sure to adhere to the Minimal,Complete Verifiable standards in the future. Thanks for going above and beyond. I was able to get both answers to work. Thanks again for the help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove

```
ax.legend(numpoints=1)
```

and add

```
plt.legend(handles=[p1,p2], bbox_to_anchor=(0.75, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

You will get only one legend.

So your code will look like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#####read and organize data
alldata = pd.read_csv('Fig_1.csv')

CondtionA = list(zip(alldata.iloc[:,1],alldata.iloc[:,2]))
ConditionB = list(zip(alldata.iloc[:,7],alldata.iloc[:,8]))

### make the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

p1 = plt.plot(alldata['Temperature'],ConditionA,linewidth = 1,c='k', linestyle = '--',label = 'ConditionA')
p2 = plt.plot(alldata['Temperature'],ConditionB,linewidth = 1,c='k', label = "ConditonB")
#ax.legend(numpoints=1)
plt.legend(handles=[p1,p2], bbox_to_anchor=(0.75, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)


plt.show()
```

Comment: I think the question is not about leaving part of the plotted data out, but to plot the data as shown, but restrict the legend to not show duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to consider my problem but as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest suggests, I want to keep both replicate for a condition present, but avoid a redundant legend.

Comment: The problem with the updated answer is that the legend titles are applied to the data sequentially, so both "ConditionA" and "ConditionB" legends show the same  dotted lines.

Comment: You can try this.  where you specify which lines should show the legends and where.


    plt.legend(handles=[p1,p2], bbox_to_anchor=(0.75, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)